# Problems sending emails via MailKit

Tags: asp.net, ssl, mailkit

I original wrote sub for sending out emails with SmtpClient that worked for some time until recently when I discovered it didn't work anymore. Some research said that protocol was depreciated and to use MailKit for sending email. So I wrote a short bit of code that seems to work intermittently. Strange because to me it either works or it doesn't, not some times. This is what I ended up writing after some research (I don't think its right).

```
using (var smtpClient = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
{
    smtpClient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
    smtpClient.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
    smtpClient.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl2;
    smtpClient.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
    smtpClient.Connect("mail.myserver.com", 465, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
    smtpClient.Authenticate("username", "pwd");
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    smtpClient.Disconnect(true);
 }
```

This is the Exception message:

> An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.
> One possibility is that you are trying to connect to a port which does not support SSL/TLS.
> The other possibility is that the SSL certificate presented by the server is not trusted by the system for one or more of the following reasons:
>
> 1. The server is using a self-signed certificate which cannot be verified.
> 2. The local system is missing a Root or Intermediate certificate needed to verify the server's certificate.
> 3. The certificate presented by the server is expired or invalid.
>    See https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#InvalidSslCertificate for possible solutions.
>    The inner Exception message:
>    Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The inner exception message is the message you should pay attention to in this case.

The remote server closed the connection.

Why? Who knows. Maybe because you are connecting and disconnecting way too often.

Many mail servers will begin to reject connections from clients that connect and disconnect too frequently.

How often are you connecting/disconnecting?

You might try keeping an SmtpClient session open for a few minutes in order to send multiple messages instead of opening a connection to send only a single message and then disconnecting.

Comment: I wish it were true, by keeping the connection open enable the mail to be sent twice but on the third attempt the same exception is thrown.

Comment: Then you aren’t properly keeping the connection alive. The server will disconnect after 10 minutes or so of inactivity. You need to call the NoOp() method to keep it alive.